# Unsafe operations... Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked... I can't seem to understand why the operation is unsafe

Tags: java, arraylist

I've read quite a few sources that talk about xlint, the unsafe operation stuff, and a lot of it has said something along the lines of:

you probably initialized your arraylist with,

```
Arraylist x = new Arraylist();
```

instead, do,

```
List<String> x = new ArrayList<String>();
```

that's all fine and dandy, but that doesn't help me at all with this situation. In my project, I'm trying to make a turn based game, and I have a Commander class that has an arraylist of units and buildings. Units are seperate objects, with subclasses. When constructing the subclasses, the Commander object is a parameter, so that's why I used this, which I assume is fine? here's where the problem is at:

```
public void buyUnit(int u)
{
    if (u < 1 || u > 23)
    {
        if (u == 1)
            this.getUnits().add(new Grunt(this));
        if (u == 2)
            this.getUnits().add(new Rifleman(this));
        if (u == 3)
            this.getUnits().add(new Scout(this));
        if (u == 4)
            this.getUnits().add(new Mortar(this));
        if (u == 5)
            this.getUnits().add(new FlakTrooper(this));
        if (u == 6)
            this.getUnits().add(new RPG(this));
        if (u == 7)
            this.getUnits().add(new Sniper(this));
        if (u == 8)
            this.getUnits().add(new Minigunner(this));
        if (u == 9)
            this.getUnits().add(new Humvee(this));
        if (u == 10)
            this.getUnits().add(new Tank(this));
        if (u == 11)
            this.getUnits().add(new Artillery(this));
        if (u == 12)
            this.getUnits().add(new MissileBattery(this));
        if (u == 13)
            this.getUnits().add(new GattlingGun(this));
        if (u == 14)
            this.getUnits().add(new IFV(this));
        if (u == 15)
            this.getUnits().add(new TankBuster(this));
        if (u == 16)
            this.getUnits().add(new Flamethrower(this));
        if (u == 17)
            this.getUnits().add(new Fighter(this));
        if (u == 18)
            this.getUnits().add(new Bomber(this));
        if (u == 19)
            this.getUnits().add(new Gunship(this));
        if (u == 20)
            this.getUnits().add(new Gunner(this));
        if (u == 21)
            this.getUnits().add(new Jet(this));
        if (u == 22)
            this.getUnits().add(new Chopper(this));
        if (u == 23)
            this.getUnits().add(new Harrier(this)); 
        this.loseBalance(units.get(units.size() - 1).getCost());
    }
```

I'm sure there's a better way to do that, rather than using an integer parameter, but I'd prefer if there's a way to fix the problem while keeping that. The last line, with the loseBalance(int b) method is fine because I get the error when I comment that out. So what's the problem?

---

Well Marco13 pointed out something out about the getUnits() method, which is:

```
public ArrayList getUnits()
{
    return units;
}
```

just to return the ArrayList of units. I still don't understand why it now works, but I switched:

```
this.getUnits(). ...
```

to

```
units. ...
```

I guess it was dumb to try to return that Arraylist in the first place when I was able to access it within the class, but that still doesn't explain why I get an error when I try to return the ecact same array, but only by using a method rather than the reference itself.

Comment: The Java way of doing this is to create a base type (Interface or Abstract Class) of your Game types and use that as the Generic List type. On the other hand, generics are compile time features of java so as long as you know what you are doing and keep an eye over different parts of code where your list is being used it would be safe to ignore the error.

Comment: What does the `getUnits()` method look like? WHERE exactly is the error happening?

Comment: This method is horrible. Delete it and pretend you never wrote anything so ugly... I'm not sure what you're trying to do but a case switch would be much more sensible. Of, better yet, a factory pattern with a visitor.

Comment: How `units` is declared?

Answer (score 2):

you have used raw type of `ArrayList` that's generating the warning.

> Never mix parametrized type with raw type.

```
public ArrayList getUnits()
{
    return units;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not quite you are asking but if you have instriction like :

```
if (u < 1 || u > 23)
    {
        if (u == 1)
            this.getUnits().add(new Grunt(this));
        if (u == 2)
            this.getUnits().add(new Rifleman(this));
    }
```

then inner if will never be true, because u has to be less than 1 or more than 23 in order to test that inner `ifs`.
It should be

```
if (u >= 1 && u <= 23)
```

that's the first thing, second, use

```
if(u==1){ 
    //code
}else if(u==2) {
    //code
}
```

instead of

```
if(u==1){}
if(u==2){}
```

because you are checking everyone of them even if there was a match already.
in your case i recommend using

```
switch(u)
{
    case 1:
        //code
        break;
    case 2:
        //code
        break;
    case 3:
        //code
        break;
    .
    .
    .
    default:
}
```

without that `if (u < 1 || u > 23)`